# How to batch remove file extensions on mac using csh or bash?

Tags: macos, command-line, file-extension, batch-rename

I wrongly added `.dcm` extension on all files on my Mac, which resulted in failure to log in on my iCloud and the storage of my key chains.

Having been so desperate to find out a solution to restore their original file extensions, but I only found answers to replace `.abc` with `.def` extensions, which is not I want. I want to remove all the redundant `.dcm` extension added on every file.

Is there a way to just delete the .dcm extensions on all files (recursively)?

These are the solutions to replacing file-extions I found:

```
for file in *.abc; do mv "$file" "${file%.abc}"; done
for old in *.abc; do mv $old basename $old .abc.ef; done
```

They are either not recursive or Bash (3.2x) says "bad substitution" / "command not found".

Comment: I'm curious what answers you found that explain how to replace something, but which would not allow you to just delete the extension?

Comment: several...since those questions are about how to replace one file extension with another such as .abc to .def, the answers are like "for file in *.abc; do mv "$file" "${file%.abc}.def"; done

Comment: Did it occur to you to simply remove the `.def` from the examples you found? Bash doesn't replace anything here… it deletes `.abc` and then you add `.def`. So you could have just left out the "add `.def`" part.

Comment: Yep, and bash says bad substitution

Comment: and this isn't recursive as well

Comment: I found others like for old in *.txt; do mv $old `basename $old .txt`.md; done. Deleting md also didn't work..

Comment: I doubt that the code you showed gives a “bad substitution” error. Indeed it's not recursive, but that could be easily changed. It'd be helpful if, when you ask a question, to explicitly add everything you've tried and explain why it didn't work. You can still [edit] your post to do that – comments aren't that useful for such things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
find / -type f -name '*.dcm' -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$0" "${0%.dcm}"' {} \;
```

The command:

- Recurses from `/`
- Finds every file named `*.dcm`
- Executes a small subshell call with one argument, the filename (`{}`)
- … which renames the file (`$0`) using `mv`
- [deleting the shortest match (`%`)](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) of `.dcm` using string manipulation

Put an `echo` in front of `mv` to see what it would do.

If you want to work without the subshell, you can pipe to `while`:

```
find / -type f -name '*.dcm' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  mv -- "$filename" "${filename%.dcm}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll play with it a bit more. And I just found another working solution: find /path/to/your/files -name '*.dcm' | while read fname; do
    mv "$fname" "${fname%.dcm}"
done

Comment: This is also good, but not that robust. See my answer for a better solution that handles all kinds of possible whitespace in filenames. (Bash is weird, but it's required: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/looping-through-files-with-spaces-in-the-names)

Comment: there's a line during the execution says: `override r-------- Apple/staff for /Users/Apple/Library/Keychains/.fl0D1D1BA9? (y/n [n])` I don't understand the content. Guess I should hit [n]?

Comment: Yep, and the one with `echo` works awesome!